# Can I hide parents with no children in a TFS query of the "tree of work items" type?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-query

As the title says, I have a "tree of work items" query that shows all `parent` work items ("Initiatives") that have a certain `State` (here: *Closed*) with their respective children which are *not closed*, so it looks something like that:

```
Parent 1 [Closed]
    Child 4 [New]
    Child 5 [Active]
Parent 2 [Closed]
Parent 3 [Closed]
    Child 2 [Ready]
    Child 4 [Active]
```

How can I filter out the parent work items that don't have any *matching* children? I.e. **Parent 2** should not show up as a result of the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Work items and direct links** type of query instead of **tree of work items**

See below screenshot: User Stores that don't have any matching children will be filtered out.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that helps :-) Is there also a way to only count the "top level" (i.e. parent) items returned by the query (e.g. for a tile on a Dashboard)?

Comment: There is an extension tool [Query Tile PRO](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mskold.mskold-Query-Tile-PRO) (In the **filter** select **TopLevel**)which can achieve this. I am afraid it cannot be done through the query.